# Error While creating a VM with managed disk using an image created by Packer

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am getting below error while running a terraform script which creates a VM with managed disks using a custom image created by Packer:

```
 azurerm_virtual_machine.test: compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidParameter" Message="Id /subscriptions/e*************************b2c/resourceGroups/A*******VM/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/myVM-image-Test is not a valid resource reference." Target="osDisk.managedDisk.id"
```

Comment: Can someone please look into this issue and help me, i can post the script if need be.

Comment: You should post the Packer and Terraform code if you want people to be able to help answer the question

Comment: Review|Help and Improvement: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question. Good luck!

Comment: Some issue is in your code "images/myVM-image-Test is not a valid resource reference" error is indicating that. Please share your code for debugging.